# Are wireless 802.11n DRAFT devices foward-compatible?

Tags: wireless-networking

Are 802.11 draft devices compatible with newer devices that are not DRAFT?

(I am wondering this because of Cisco Linksys e1000 router which seems to be a 802.11 DRAFT device)

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing for my Asus RT-N16.

Answer (score 1):

Draft devices should be compliant.  It just means that the firmware was written before the standard was finalised and hasn't been rewritten, typically because it works.  This should at least be the case for the big name manufacturers.